# How Docker RUN mount=type=cache works?

Tags: docker, caching, dockerfile, docker-buildkit, buildx

> Aside from the ADD and COPY commands, cache checking does not look at the files in the container to determine a cache match. For example, when processing a RUN apt-get -y update command the files updated in the container are not examined to determine if a cache hit exists. In that case just the command string itself is used to find a match.

source: [https://docker-docs.uclv.cu/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#:~:text=Aside%20from%20the%20ADD%20and,if%20a%20cache%20hit%20exists](https://docker-docs.uclv.cu/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#:%7E:text=Aside%20from%20the%20ADD%20and,if%20a%20cache%20hit%20exists).

With mount=type=cache, cache checking will look at the files into target location? How does the "look" works? Comparing cache metadata?

Comment: please refer to the github discussion. https://github.com/moby/buildkit/discussions/4174